# Configure Database Controler using Internal Ip of server

Tags: performance, appdynamics

I am installing the appdynamic agent to my Microsoft SQL Server.

I am able to connect to the Agent but on step 6 Configure the Database Collector I am using the internal ip of my server instead of public Ip. My server only accessible using internal IP through VPN.

after using the internal/private Ip  I am stuck on point 7 Connect Database to the Appdynamic Controler

Can anyone help here to fix this issue or to configure the agent on the server that is just accessible through the private ip?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically AppDynamics will connect to da database in the following order:

Controller -> DB agent -> your database

The DB agent can either be the one running on your controller or a seperate agent not running on you controller (but reporting the db data to it)

Can you tell me more about your setup in those terms ?

For example, my company prohibits our databases from connecting/accepting connections to/from the internet, to bypass that restriction we have setup a DB agent on a linux box inside our datacenter and we use that to connect to our databases.

So even before you answer my question i can already tell you that its the DB agent that will take the ip/fqdn and use it to initiate a connection, if the db agent and the db are on the same internal network, then internal IP should work.

regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the main controller is SaaS based or on premise.

If it is SaaS then I'd suggest to go with AppD for Database as a separate controller and then use it to feed the information to the main controller. Speak to one of AppD professional services about this setup.